# How to convert Milliseconds array to MM:SS:ss format or DateTime format in Julia?

Tags: datetime, julia, milliseconds

I am trying to convert milliseconds to minutes but unable to do so. I have been expecting the result in the form of
MM:SS
I have saved my results in a dataframe which shows the data type as milliseconds and even when I divide the entire row by 60000, the data type still remains to be milliseconds

```
delivery_time = delivery_timestamp - init_timestamp
783358-element Array{Millisecond,1}:
 34200000 milliseconds
 14580000 milliseconds
 27300000 milliseconds
 9180000 milliseconds 
 13560000 milliseconds
 6960000 milliseconds 
 12600000 milliseconds
 9600000 milliseconds 
 7500000 milliseconds 
 13080000 milliseconds
 9180000 milliseconds 
 9600000 milliseconds 
 27660000 milliseconds
 ⋮                    

delivery_time = (delivery_time)/60000
783358-element Array{Millisecond,1}:
 570 milliseconds
 243 milliseconds
 455 milliseconds
 153 milliseconds
 226 milliseconds
 116 milliseconds
 210 milliseconds
 160 milliseconds
 125 milliseconds
 218 milliseconds
 153 milliseconds
```

I am expecting the results to be

```
df.delivery_time
06:22
07:32
09:51
.
.
.
```

or even if I can get results as

```
df.delivery_time
570 minute
243 minute
455 minute
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `Millisecond` to eg. `Minute` only with loss of precision. Here is an example that does rounding to the nearest minute:

```
@. Minute(round(Int, Dates.value(delivery_time) / (1000 * 60)))
```

If you do not need `Minute` values but simply floats without rounding you can do:

```
@. Dates.value(delivery_time) / (1000 * 60)
```

or e.g.

```
Dates.value.(delivery_time) / (1000 * 60)
```

if you prefer not to use `@.`.

Finally you can write

```
Time(0) .+ delivery_time
```

which is lossless, but now the returned object is not a subtype of `Period` and it will "wrap around" 24 hours. If you want to avoid wrapping use `DateTime` instead of `Time` above.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for help. You solved most of my problem. I am quite naive yet in Julia started a week back.
I had actually used - 
`df.delivery_time = map((x) -> convert(Time,x),df[:15])`
with this as the result
`783358-element Array{Time,1}:`
`09:30:00`
`04:03:00`
`07:35:00`
`02:33:00`
`03:46:00`
`01:56:00`

Comment: You can write this shorter as `convert.(Time, df[:15])`. However, `df[:15]` is the same as `df[15]` (15th column of data frame `df`) and this means that your column 15 does not hold `Millisecond` values. If it did then this operation would fail.